# Strings expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, d3.js, expression

I am plotting a d3 graph, and I have an array of strings in my data set, that provides with some timestamps, the timestamps are like
 "ON 8:34  OFF 9:15" and I wish to extract the numbers out of it.
I know it's fairly simple, however I can seem to find a way about it, I am new to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression.

```
//It will return you an array of matched strings
"ON 8:34 OFF 9:15".match(/\d+:\d+/g);
```

```js
document.write("ON 8:34 OFF 9:15".match(/\d+:\d+/g).join())
```